# Subir imagen con fetch en Vuetify

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuetify

Trabajando en un formulario en Vuetify 2.0, con campos de texto, numéricos y la necesidad de subir una imagen, planteo el siguiente código:

```html
<v-form ref="form_create" v-model="valid_create" lazy-validation>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-text-field label="Descripcion" v-model="n_expo.descripcion" required :rules="rules_descripcion"></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="12">
      <v-file-input v-model="file_image" prepend-icon="mdi-camera" accept="image/*" label="Imagen"></v-file-input>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <!--.....-->
  <v-btn color="primary" :disabled="!valid_create" class="text-body-1 text-button" @click="nuevo()">Guardar</v-btn>
</v-form>
```

En el método nuevo() construyo el FormData para enviarlo al servidor y capturar los datos desde un script PHP. Teniendo en cuenta que todos los datos del formulario los cargo en el objeto n_expo y el archivo de imagen en file_image.

```html
nuevo() {

    let __this = this;
    __this.dialog_create = true;
    __this.$refs.form_create.validate();

    let url = "https://www.dir.com";

    var formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append("file", __this.file_image);
    formData.append("expo", __this.n_expo);

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        body: formData
    }


    window.fetch(url, options)
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (function(response) {
            console.log(response);
  })
}
```

No encuentro la forma de capturar estos datos desde el archivo PHP, es correcto este planteamiento para enviar los datos y la imagen o hay que plantearlo de otra forma?